# How to access variables from .yaml file to robot framework script?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have Myvariable.yaml file and sample.robot file, I wanted to use the variables from .yaml file to robot file

- Myvariable.yaml file:

  ```
     ACFC NEWS:
          Doc_Title:  XPath=//div[@class='ng-scope']
          Open_Selector:  xpath=//button[@class='btn btn-default ng-binding]
  ```
- Sample.robot file

  ```
     ***Settings****
     Variables  Myvariable.yaml

     ***Keywords****
     Choose Topic:
          Input Text   ${Doc_Title}   "Some text"
          Click Button   ${Open_Selector}
  ```

> Error: Variable not found

It would be great if any one can help me in solving this issue.

Comment: your code is not properly formatted, always paste code with proper formatting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to access the attributes of yaml file like  `${DICT.one}`
more information  here

https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/userguide/src/CreatingTestData/ResourceAndVariableFiles.rst#variable-file-as-yaml

your modified code

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    Myvariable.yaml

*** Test Case ***
Test
    Choose Topic
***Keywords****
Choose Topic
       Log   ${ACFC NEWS.Doc_Title}
       Log   ${ACFC NEWS.Open_Selector}
```

I am assuming you are running the script with below command

```
pybot -V myvariable.yaml sample.robot
```

This should solve your problem now.

Comment: Excellent the problem is solved now. Thank you o much for the help Pankaj

Comment: is there a way to make this work for multiple files? Like I want to send var1.yaml to robot1 and vars2.yaml to robot2 in same run (but I dont want them to see each others variables). Would something like this work ? `robot -V vars1.yaml robot1.robot -V vars2.yaml robot2.robot`